# mutate() doesn't add new column to existing data frame when using custom function within mutate()

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

When I use mutate() to try to add a new column to a dataframe by applying a custom function(temp.conv) to an existing column, the output shows that R has calculated the values using the custom function but does not add those values to a new column.

```
a<-mutate(air_qual,
  TempC = temp.converter(Temp,"F2C")
)
```

Custom temperature conversion function:

```
temp.converter<-function(temp,scale_in2scale_out){
  if (scale_in2scale_out=="C2F") {
    temp*9/5+32
  } else if(scale_in2scale_out=="F2C"){
    (temp-32)*5/9
  } else if(scale_in2scale_out=="K2C"){
    temp-273
  } else if(scale_in2scale_out=="C2K"){
    temp+273
  } else if(scale_in2scale_out=="F2K"){
    (temp-32)*5/9+273
  } else if(scale_in2scale_out=="K2F"){
    (temp-273)*9/5+32
  }
}
```

output:

```
>a3<- mutate(airquality, tempC=temp.converter(Temp,"F2C"))
19.44444 22.22222 23.33333 16.66667 13.33333 18.88889 18.33333 15 16.11111 20.55556 2
33.88889 33.88889 30.55556 28.88889 26.66667 25.55556 23.88889 22.77778 27.22222 24.44444 25 21.66667
21.66667 25.55556 19.44444 24.44444 20 27.77778 17.77778 21.66667 27.22222 20.55556 17.22222
21.11111 25 23.88889 24.44444 20 Celsiu`s`
> a3
    Ozone Solar.R Wind Temp Month Day
1      41     190  7.4   67     5   1
2      36     118  8.0   72     5   2
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior (R-4.0.2, dplyr-1.0.0, win10). I suggest you try this in a fresh R instance. (Side notes: (1) Your `temp.converter` function might be easier to read if you used `switch(scale_in2scale_out[1], ...)`. (2) The offset between celsius and kelvin is 273.15, not 273.)

Comment: `dplyr::case_when` is a much cleaner way to implement what your temp.converter is doing.